# How can I use edebug with cl-block?

Tags: edebug, cl-lib

Given the following function using cl-block:

```el
(defun wh/with-block (x)
  (cl-block 'foo
    (+ x 1)))
```

I can evaluate it, but `C-u M-x edebug-eval-defun` gives an error: `edebug-syntax-error: Invalid read syntax: symbolp, "failed"`.

Why is this? Is this an Emacs bug, or am I using edebug incorrectly?

Comment: Edebug is right: The tag is not evaluated and needs to be a symbol, not `(quote foo)`.

Comment: @politza aha, you're right! Would you like to add an answer?

Comment: @politza: well "right" is debatable: I agree that the code is incorrect but `Invalid read syntax: symbolp, "failed"` does not seem like the right characterization of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Edebug is arguably right: The tag is not evaluated and needs to be a symbol, not `(quote foo)`.